# 総当たりレーベンシュタイン距離

Tags: python

複数の文字列データ同士の組み合わせから、総当たりのレーベンシュタイン距離を計算し、
最もレーベンシュタイン距離の小さい組み合わせを探そうとしています。

```
# levendist.py

import numpy as np
def levenshtein(source, target):
    if len(source) < len(target):
        return levenshtein(target, source)

    # So now we have len(source) >= len(target).
    if len(target) == 0:
        return len(source)

    # We call tuple() to force strings to be used as sequences
    # ('c', 'a', 't', 's') - numpy uses them as values by default.
    source = np.array(tuple(source))
    target = np.array(tuple(target))

    # We use a dynamic programming algorithm, but with the
    # added optimization that we only need the last two rows
    # of the matrix.
    previous_row = np.arange(target.size + 1)
    for s in source:
        # Insertion (target grows longer than source):
        current_row = previous_row + 1

        # Substitution or matching:
        # Target and source items are aligned, and either
        # are different (cost of 1), or are the same (cost of 0).
        current_row[1:] = np.minimum(
                current_row[1:],
                np.add(previous_row[:-1], target != s))

        # Deletion (target grows shorter than source):
        current_row[1:] = np.minimum(
                current_row[1:],
                current_row[0:-1] + 1)

        previous_row = current_row

    return previous_row[-1]
```

上のモジュールでlevenshteinを定義して、
下で2つの文字列配列を総当たりで調べようとしています。

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape(2)
```

と出てしまいます。

```
import numpy as np
import levendist as leven

lst1 = np.array([[1],[2]])
lst2 = np.array([3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
#print(lst1.shape)
#print(lst2.shape)

lst3=leven.levenshtein(lst1,lst2)

print(lst3.shape)
print(lst3)

print(np.max(lst3, axis = 1))
lst4 = np.max(lst3, axis = 1)
print(lst4.shape)
```

Llevenshteinでsourceとtargetを入れ替えているからかもしれませんが、どのようにかして総当たりのレーベンシュタイン距離を求められないでしょう。

Comment: 「2つの文字列配列」と書かれていますが、プログラム中では int の配列になっていますね…また、`levendist.py:levendist()` function の最初の `if len(source) = len(target).` は書き間違いでしょうか？

Comment: おっしゃる通りです。計算上差異はないかと考え、数字にしておりました。実際は文字列です。levendist.py:levendist() functionの最初のif len(source) = len(target). の最後の”.”は”:”の書き間違えです。

Comment: ：以外にもインデントが不正でした。そもそも、'target'が'source'より長い場合は、'target'と'source'を入れ替えろというif文のはずですが、うまく反映されていないようです。

Comment: @KojiroIkeda この画像はなんでしょうか？StackOverflowではMarkdown記法でコードを表示するため、コードをハイライトしたいのであればMarkdown記法を用いてください。コードを選択して`{}`ボタンを押すことでMarkdown記法に自動で変換することも可能です。

Comment: 元ネタは [Algorithm Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python) の `5th, a vectorized version` でしょうか。最後に `Note this implementation only works if the weight does not depend on the character edited` と書かれていますね。

Comment: @Myaku おっしゃる通りです。例に倣って記述したつもりですが、うまくいっていないようです。

Comment: @mjy 写真に関して、その通りです。ご教授ありがとうございます。lst1とlst2を普通のリストにして、2重のfor文で総当たりでlevendistの結果を出力し、lst1の要素数xlst2の要素数の配列（行列？）にそれらを入れることで、解決しました。皆さまコメントありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lst1`と`lst2`の形が異なっていたため、flatten して普通のリストにして、2重のfor文で総当たりで`levendist`の結果を出力し、`lst1`の要素数x`lst2`の要素数の2次元配列（行列？）にそれらを入れた後最小の要素を見つけました。

```
import levendist as leven
import numpy as np

lst1 = np.array([["abc"], ["def"]])
# 文字列の配列に
lst1 = lst1.flatten()
lst2 = np.array(["ab", "cdef", "ghijk", "lmn"])

levs = np.zeros( (lst1.size, lst2.size), dtype=np.int)
for i, elm1 in enumerate(lst1):
    for ii, elm2 in enumerate(lst2):
        levs[i, ii] = leven.levenshtein(elm1, elm2)

print("# レーベンシュタイン距離が最小の組合せ")
min_lev = levs.min()
print("距離:", min_lev)
print("組み合せ:")
for i in np.argwhere(levs == min_lev):
    print("   ", lst1[i[0]], lst2[i[1]])
```

出力:

```
# レーベンシュタイン距離が最小の組合せ
距離: 1
組み合せ:
    abc ab
    def cdef
```

<sub>-- この回答は、[質問者さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/21201/kojiro-ikeda)の[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33551/%E7%B7%8F%E5%BD%93%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E8%B7%9D%E9%9B%A2#comment33397_33551)を元に推測も含め編集したものです。</sub>

Comment: 何となく理解できた気がしたので、コードを追加してみました。
質問者さんのコードの `1〜9` の数値は、実際にはそれぞれが文字列であった、という理解です。
言わんとすることと違う場合はロールバックして下さい。
（的外れあるいはノイズになりそうな私のコメントは消しておきます）

Comment: @mjy さん、ありがとうございます！　私の理解も追加して頂いたコードと同じものです。